# Why am I not seeing the contents of a localhost s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, localstack

Using localstack package
I have the following:

```
awslocal s3 mb s3://kiosks-images
awslocal s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket kiosks-images --acl public-read
awslocal s3 cp TopCroppedSpotlightLowExOnlyPGV.jpg s3://kiosks-images/dev/us/2020_08_11/eea9efc9-5970-426b-b867-9f57d6d9548f/55208151-6438-4bfc-b4be-43ed57798dc2

aws s3 ls s3://kiosks-images
                           PRE dev/
                           PRE prod/
                           PRE qa/
```

how do I ensure the file I added is copied to a correct place in the bucket?

Comment: What about that output is not what you expected?

Comment: how do I validate that s3://kiosks-images/dev/us/2020_08_11/eea9efc9-5970-426b-b867-9f57d6d9548f/55208151-6438-4bfc-b4be-43ed57798dc2 is actually added?

I dont even see a dev/us directory

Comment: Either use `--recursive` on the ls call to show all objects, or list the full S3 URI to see that file on S3.

Comment: that is answer mark it so and I will mark it as answered, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you list objects in a bucket, S3 collapses any objects with the same prefix before the separator as one entry, and marks this collection as `PRE` in the output.  This lets you treat the contents of S3 buckets as a traditional filesystem with directories and files in those directories.

You can either use `aws s3 ls --recursive` to list all objects in a bucket, or query the object directly by doing something like `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/path/to/object` to view that single object, if it exists.